# jQuery gradual animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have this issue with my jquery plugin atm which is used alongside jquery mobile. I have an animate function which looks like this:

```
    animateWheel: function (self, speed, count) {
        var $item = $(self.settings.itemClass).first();
        var width = $item.outerWidth(true);

        $item.animate({ "left": "-" + width + "px" }, {
            duration: speed,
            easing: "linear",
            step: function (now, fx) {
                $(self.settings.itemClass + ":gt(0)").css("left", now);
            },
            complete: function () {
                self.moveItem(self, speed, count);
            }
        });
    },
    moveItem: function (self, speed, count) {
        if (count > 0) {
            var $item = $(self.settings.itemClass).first();
            $item.hide(speed, "linear", function () {
                $(this).appendTo(self.settings.itemContainerClass).show(speed, "linear");
                self.moveItem(self, speed, count - 1); // Repeat
            });
        }
    }
```

As you can see when **animateWheel** is called, it gets the first item and then animates it. The **step** function animates the rest of the items (there could be hundreds). This animation only happens once. When the animation is complete it calls **moveItem** which you can see moves the first item to the end of the array of elements and calls **moveItem** again until the counter is at 0.
These all using the linear easing to make it looks smooth.

This all works fine and can be viewed at [url=http://www.r3plica.co.uk]Winner Select[/url] but my issue is that I want the animation to start slowly and then speed up and finally slow down and stop. 
To get a decent Idea, imagine wheel of fortune and that should give you an idea of what I am after. The problem is, I am unsure how to do this.

What I think needs to be done, is to alter the speed as the function (**moveItem**) is called starting from a low speed, then speeding up and finally slowing down to a stop.

My html looks like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="carouselPage">

    <div data-role="header">
        <img src="assets/css/images/logo.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-container">

                <div class="carousel-item red">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item orange">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item green">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item navy">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item blue">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item teal">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item red">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item orange">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item green">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item navy">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item blue">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item teal">
                    <div class="carousel-photo">
                        <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-content ">
                        <p>Jaymie<br />Jeffrey</p>
                        <span class="twitter">
                            <p>@JaymieJeffrey</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it :)

/r3plica

**Update 1**

I have now managed to get some sort of easing involved by doing this:

```
animateWheel: function (self, speed) {
    var $item = $(self.settings.itemClass).first();
    var width = $item.outerWidth(true);

    $item.animate({ "left": "-" + width + "px" }, {
        duration: speed,
        easing: "linear",
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $(self.settings.itemClass + ":gt(0)").css("left", now);
        },
        complete: function () {
            var random = Math.random() * 5;
            var duration = 1000 + Math.floor(1000 * random); // min: 1000, max: 6000

            $({ speed: 0 }).animate({ speed: 100 }, {
                duration: duration,
                easing: 'easeInBack', // can be anything
                step: function () { // called on every step
                    var $item = $(self.settings.itemClass).first();

                    $item.hide(Math.ceil(this.speed), "linear", function () {
                        $(this).appendTo(self.settings.itemContainerClass).show(this.speed, "linear");
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

You can see the results at http://www.r3plica.co.uk

Comment: You're looking for "easing".  There aren't many defined with default jquery, but other addons (such as jquery UI) have a whole bunch more.

Comment: easing applies to one animation though right? I am animating multiple objects at the same time.

Comment: I don't see any reason you're doing all of that with the `animate`.  Just call animate on all of your items, you don't need to sync them yourself.  Even so, I don't see why you can't use an easing.  A jsfiddle demo would probably help here.

Comment: you can see the result at http://www.r3plica.co.uk

Comment: the reason for the "doing all of that" is because the first item needs to be moved to the end of the collection as the animation is processing. I can't really do that, although thinking about it I guess I could do it on the step of the first animation....... I shall have a look and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try messing with different easing types here is a really useful cheat sheet I use.

http://easings.net/

I was thinking you would probably want something like easeInOutBack maybe?

Comment: Doesn't easing only apply to one element I am animating? If so, I am animating multiple elements (hence the step function) and then animating again when the first animation is complete (hence the complete function). I have updated my question to include the "moveItem" function so you can see how that works

Comment: I think what I need to do is to adjust the timing as it executes.